# How to use SharedPreferences with api form data and keep user logedin?

Tags: flutter, api

I want to keep user logedin with api.
here is my response.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "user": {
    "user_id": "6108066c7de61",
    "name": "SC",
    "mobile": "8154993851",
    "email": "sc@mailinator.com",
    "standard_id": "5d170c5a5609a",
    "medium_id": "5d1594ae58457",
    "location": "",
    "avatar": null,
    "device_id": "---",
    "created_at": "2021-08-02",
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "user_plan": {
    "order_id": "162791605461080716777c918194647156108066c7de62",
    "plan_id": "5d1d7859d0923",
    "plan_name": "Diamond",
    "access_level": "s",
    "total": "0",
    "validity": "12",
    "validity_type": "months",
    "material": "1",
    "video": "1",
    "quiz": "1",
    "valid_from": "2021-08-02",
    "valid_to": "2022-08-02",
    "transaction_date": "2021-08-02 20:24:14",
    "active": "1"
  },
  "standard": {
    "standard_id": "5d170c5a5609a",
    "standard_name": "Std 12 Science - A ( PCM Full Course )",
    "active": "1"
  },
  "medium": {
    "medium_id": "5d1594ae58457",
    "medium_name": "Gujarati Medium",
    "active": "1"
  }
}
```

Here is Model Class from above response in login_model.dart file.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final loginModel = loginModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

LoginModel loginModelFromJson(String str) =>
    LoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginModelToJson(LoginModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginModel {
  LoginModel({
    required this.success,
    required this.user,
    required this.userPlan,
    required this.standard,
    required this.medium,
  });

  int success;
  LogedinUser? user;
  UserPlan? userPlan;
  UserStandard? standard;
  UserMedium? medium;

  factory LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginModel(
        success: json["success"] == null ? null : json["success"],
        user: json["user"] == null ? null : LogedinUser.fromJson(json["user"]),
        userPlan: json["user_plan"] == null
            ? null
            : UserPlan.fromJson(json["user_plan"]),
        standard: json["standard"] == null
            ? null
            : UserStandard.fromJson(json["standard"]),
        medium:
            json["medium"] == null ? null : UserMedium.fromJson(json["medium"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success == null ? null : success,
        "user": user == null ? null : user?.toJson(),
        "user_plan": userPlan == null ? null : userPlan?.toJson(),
        "standard": standard == null ? null : standard?.toJson(),
        "medium": medium == null ? null : medium?.toJson(),
      };
}

class UserMedium {
  UserMedium({
    required this.mediumId,
    required this.mediumName,
    required this.active,
  });

  String? mediumId;
  String? mediumName;
  String? active;

  factory UserMedium.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserMedium(
        mediumId: json["medium_id"] == null ? null : json["medium_id"],
        mediumName: json["medium_name"] == null ? null : json["medium_name"],
        active: json["active"] == null ? null : json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "medium_id": mediumId == null ? null : mediumId,
        "medium_name": mediumName == null ? null : mediumName,
        "active": active == null ? null : active,
      };
}

class UserStandard {
  UserStandard({
    required this.standardId,
    required this.standardName,
    required this.active,
  });

  String? standardId;
  String? standardName;
  String? active;

  factory UserStandard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserStandard(
        standardId: json["standard_id"] == null ? null : json["standard_id"],
        standardName:
            json["standard_name"] == null ? null : json["standard_name"],
        active: json["active"] == null ? null : json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "standard_id": standardId == null ? null : standardId,
        "standard_name": standardName == null ? null : standardName,
        "active": active == null ? null : active,
      };
}

class LogedinUser {
  LogedinUser({
    required this.userId,
    required this.name,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.email,
    required this.standardId,
    required this.mediumId,
    required this.location,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.deviceId,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  String? userId;
  String? name;
  String? mobile;
  String? email;
  String? standardId;
  String? mediumId;
  String? location;
  dynamic avatar;
  String? deviceId;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  dynamic updatedAt;

  factory LogedinUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LogedinUser(
        userId: json["user_id"] == null ? null : json["user_id"],
        name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
        mobile: json["mobile"] == null ? null : json["mobile"],
        email: json["email"] == null ? null : json["email"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"] == null ? null : json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"] == null ? null : json["medium_id"],
        location: json["location"] == null ? null : json["location"],
        avatar: json["avatar"],
        deviceId: json["device_id"] == null ? null : json["device_id"],
        createdAt: json["created_at"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: json["updated_at"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "user_id": userId == null ? null : userId,
        "name": name == null ? null : name,
        "mobile": mobile == null ? null : mobile,
        "email": email == null ? null : email,
        "standard_id": standardId == null ? null : standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId == null ? null : mediumId,
        "location": location == null ? null : location,
        "avatar": avatar,
        "device_id": deviceId == null ? null : deviceId,
        "created_at": createdAt == null
            ? null
            : "${createdAt?.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${createdAt?.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${createdAt?.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "updated_at": updatedAt,
      };
}

class UserPlan {
  UserPlan({
    required this.orderId,
    required this.planId,
    required this.planName,
    required this.accessLevel,
    required this.total,
    required this.validity,
    required this.validityType,
    required this.material,
    required this.video,
    required this.quiz,
    required this.validFrom,
    required this.validTo,
    required this.transactionDate,
    required this.active,
  });

  String? orderId;
  String? planId;
  String? planName;
  String? accessLevel;
  String? total;
  String? validity;
  String? validityType;
  String? material;
  String? video;
  String? quiz;
  DateTime? validFrom;
  DateTime? validTo;
  DateTime? transactionDate;
  String? active;

  factory UserPlan.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserPlan(
        orderId: json["order_id"] == null ? null : json["order_id"],
        planId: json["plan_id"] == null ? null : json["plan_id"],
        planName: json["plan_name"] == null ? null : json["plan_name"],
        accessLevel: json["access_level"] == null ? null : json["access_level"],
        total: json["total"] == null ? null : json["total"],
        validity: json["validity"] == null ? null : json["validity"],
        validityType:
            json["validity_type"] == null ? null : json["validity_type"],
        material: json["material"] == null ? null : json["material"],
        video: json["video"] == null ? null : json["video"],
        quiz: json["quiz"] == null ? null : json["quiz"],
        validFrom: json["valid_from"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["valid_from"]),
        validTo:
            json["valid_to"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["valid_to"]),
        transactionDate: json["transaction_date"] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json["transaction_date"]),
        active: json["active"] == null ? null : json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "order_id": orderId == null ? null : orderId,
        "plan_id": planId == null ? null : planId,
        "plan_name": planName == null ? null : planName,
        "access_level": accessLevel == null ? null : accessLevel,
        "total": total == null ? null : total,
        "validity": validity == null ? null : validity,
        "validity_type": validityType == null ? null : validityType,
        "material": material == null ? null : material,
        "video": video == null ? null : video,
        "quiz": quiz == null ? null : quiz,
        "valid_from": validFrom == null
            ? null
            : "${validFrom?.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${validFrom?.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${validFrom?.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "valid_to": validTo == null
            ? null
            : "${validTo?.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${validTo?.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${validTo?.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "transaction_date":
            transactionDate == null ? null : transactionDate?.toIso8601String(),
        "active": active == null ? null : active,
      };
}
```

here is my Function in api_manager.dart file.

```
Future userLogin(
    context,
    String mobile,
    String standardId,
    String mediumId,
  ) async {
    final String loginUrl = "$baseUrl/user/login";
    

    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'mobile': mobile,
      'standard_id': standardId,
      'medium_id': mediumId,
    });

    

    var response = await dio.post(loginUrl, data: formData);
    final logedinUserData = loginModelFromJson(response.data);
    final LogedinUser? userData = logedinUserData.user;
    final UserPlan? userPlan = logedinUserData.userPlan;
    final status = logedinUserData.success;
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var res = response.data;
      print("Response:=> " + res);
      print(status);
      if (status == 1) {
        
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DashBoard(
                      user: userData,
                      userPlan: userPlan,
                    )));
        
        print(userData!.name);
        return userData;
      } 
    } else {
      print('Failed to login.');
    }
  }
```

And here is my submit button code as below.

```
onPressed: () {
                          if (validateAndSave()) {
                            setState(() {
                              this.isApiCallProcess = true;
                              ApiManager().userLogin(
                                context,
                                _mobileController.text,
                                standardId,
                                mediumId,
                              );
                            });
                          }
                        }
```

As above Code how can i keep user logedin with form data.

My login functionality works perfectly.

But how can i keep user logedin

Answer (score 1):

first of use tokens for login and logout to keep user logged in or out on userLogin on status==1 when your'e sure user is logged in implement shared preferences example

```
    if (status == 1) {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', "true");
}
```

then on Main  check sharedPreference first

```
 Future<bool> isUserLoggedIn() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn'') ?? false;
  }

  void loginStatus() {
    isUserLoggedIn().then((isLoggedIn) {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        // goto dashboard
      } else {
        // goto login page
      }
    });
  }
```

logout

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreference = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    keys.remove("isLoggedIn");
```

Comment: return prefs.getBool(isLoggedIn) ?? false;  in this line isLoggedIn is undifined please can you help me.

Comment: can i have to put in ' ' or "  "?

Comment: @DhavalChaudhari  edited my ans don't forget to up vote it it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set bool in SharedPreferences when your login success

```
Future userLogin(
    context,
    String mobile,
    String standardId,
    String mediumId,
  ) async {
    final String loginUrl = "$baseUrl/user/login";
    

    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'mobile': mobile,
      'standard_id': standardId,
      'medium_id': mediumId,
    });

    

    var response = await dio.post(loginUrl, data: formData);
    final logedinUserData = loginModelFromJson(response.data);
    final LogedinUser? userData = logedinUserData.user;
    final UserPlan? userPlan = logedinUserData.userPlan;
    final status = logedinUserData.success;
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var res = response.data;
      print("Response:=> " + res);
      print(status);
      if (status == 1) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          prefs.setBool("IsLoggedin", true);
        Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DashBoard(
                      user: userData,
                      userPlan: userPlan,
                    )));
        
        print(userData!.name);
        return userData;
      } 
    } else {
      print('Failed to login.');
    }
  }
```

then when you open the app you need to check if the user logged in

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final bool logedin = await prefs.getBool('IsLoggedin') ?? false;
```